# Why does my spreadsheet function behave differently than when called from code?

Tags: vba, spreadsheet, user-defined-functions

When I call the function from Excel (in a cell):

```
=allVlookup(O24,A:D,3,"")
```

vs via vba

```
MsgBox allVlookup(Range("O24"), Range("A:D"), 3, "")
```

I get different results. When called from Excel, I only get the first match, but when calling from a vba test sub with identical parameters (except adding `Range` to the arguments to allow the sub to run), I get the full results (which is more than one).

The function I am using is:

```
Public Function allVlookup(lookupRange As Range, tableRange As Range, colIndex As Integer, Optional delimiter As String = "") As String

    Dim c As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String
    'MsgBox tableRange.Address  ' this is correct
    'With Sheets(4).Range("A1:C12").Columns(1)
    'With Range("A1:C12").Columns(1)

    'this doesn't allow things to work right either (???)
    'Set tableRange = Range("A:D")
    'Set lookupRange = Range("O24")

    'search only the first column for matches
    With tableRange.Columns(1)
        Set c = .Find(what:=lookupRange.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Not c Is Nothing Then

            firstAddress = c.Address

            Do
                'add the delimiter
                If (allVlookup <> "") Then
                    allVlookup = allVlookup + delimiter
                End If

                'append value to previous value
                allVlookup = allVlookup + c.Offset(0, colIndex).Value


                Set c = .FindNext(c)
                'exit conditions
                'no match found
                If (c Is Nothing) Then
                    Exit Do
                    'we're back to start
                ElseIf (c.Address = firstAddress) Then
                    Exit Do
                End If

            Loop
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

I am at a loss to explain why this is happening.

What can I do to get the outputs to be identical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it only gives the first match is because of a bug. Please see this [link](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) (SECTION 5) at the bottom.

I have already filed it as a bug long time ago. If you read the above link then I have suggested an alternative code as well.

**Extract from that link in case the link ever dies (which it shouldn't)**

.FindNext doesn’t work in a User-Defined Function as expected. You can use it in a normal function.

Lets Say We have this data in Sheet1:

```
A1 → Colt
A2 → Holt
A3 → Dolt
A4 → Hello
```

and in

```
B1 → olt
```

Now if we paste the below code in a module and run it then we will get the expected result as `$A$1:$A$3`

```
Sub Test()
    Sample Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1"), Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4")
End Sub
 
Sub Sample(FirstRange As Range, ListRange As Range)
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range, oRange As Range
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean
    Set oRange = ListRange.Find(what:=FirstRange.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    ExitLoop = False
    If Not oRange Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = oRange: Set aCell = oRange
 
        Do While ExitLoop = False
            Set oRange = ListRange.FindNext(After:=oRange)
 
            If Not oRange Is Nothing Then
                If oRange.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                Set aCell = Union(aCell, oRange)
            Else
                ExitLoop = True
            End If
        Loop
        MsgBox aCell.Address
    Else
        MsgBox "Not Found"
    End If
End Sub
```

However it would not work as expected if you paste this function in a module and call it from a worksheet as (Say in Cell C1) `=FindRange(A1,A1:A5)`

The code will only give you the 1st instance of the value found and ignore the rest

And hence the result that you will get is $A$2!!!

```
Function FindRange(FirstRange As Range, ListRange As Range) As String
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range, oRange As Range
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean
    Set oRange = ListRange.Find(what:=FirstRange.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    ExitLoop = False
    If Not oRange Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = oRange: Set aCell = oRange
 
        Do While ExitLoop = False
            Set oRange = ListRange.FindNext(After:=oRange)
 
            If Not oRange Is Nothing Then
                If oRange.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                Set aCell = Union(aCell, oRange)
            Else
                ExitLoop = True
            End If
        Loop
        FindRange = aCell.Address
    Else
        FindRange = "Not Found"
    End If
End Function
```

We need to approach this from a different angle.

Instead of using .FindNext we use .Find again till we get the desired result ($A$1:$A$3). See the code below which works:

```
Function FindRange(FirstRange As Range, ListRange As Range) As String
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range, oRange As Range
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean
    Set oRange = ListRange.Find(what:=FirstRange.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    ExitLoop = False
    If Not oRange Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = oRange: Set aCell = oRange
 
        Do While ExitLoop = False
            Set oRange = ListRange.Find(what:=FirstRange.Value, After:=oRange, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not oRange Is Nothing Then
                If oRange.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                Set aCell = Union(aCell, oRange)
            Else
                ExitLoop = True
            End If
        Loop
        FindRange = aCell.Address
    Else
        FindRange = "Not Found"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I can live with this being a bug. Annoying, but, good to know.

Comment: Extract from that link in case the link ever dies (which it shouldn't) -- it died :)

Comment: @SamV: Thanks for letting me know. I updated it. My site was hacked and I had to rebuilt it :)

Answer (score 3):

Change `.Find` line into:

```
Set c = .Find(what:=lookupRange.Value2, after:=.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

and additionally change `.FindNext` into:

```
Set c = .Find(what:=lookupRange.Value2, after:=c, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

Please keep also in mind that `tableRange` range should have column titles. If not, the results order would not be as expected.

Additional (EDITED) explanation for last sentence. If you have table of that type:

```
    |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
  --+-----+-----+-----+-----+
  1 | ABC    1     2     A
  2 | ABC    3     4     B
  3 | ABC    5     6     C
```

when searching of ABC in `range("A1:D3")` to get data from column D you would get as result: `BCD`. To get `ABC` there should be column titles in the first row.

Comment: This seems to work well - do you have suggestions if `tableRange` does NOT have headings?

Comment: Also, what is it that makes this work (and my uses of .Find not work)? Maybe .FindNext cannot be called from a UDF