# FindNext of vba not working

Tags: excel, vba

This is very basic question and don't scream at me coz i am not a vba expert.

So here we go, I created below vba function

```
Public Function GetDuplicateCount(value As String) As Integer

    Dim counter As Integer

    counter = 0

    With Worksheets(1).Range("A:A")
        Set c = .Find(value, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)

        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                counter = counter + 1
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing

        End If
    End With

    GetDuplicateCount = counter
End Function
```

Below is my excel values

A

1 IND

2 USA

3 CAN

4 IND

5 CAN

6 USA

Every time i search with any value it returns one don't know wny. Anything wrong with the function?

e.g. GetDuplicateCount("IND")

Comment: which is strange `.FindNext` is not working within `Function` but it's working in `Sub`. You need to use `.Find` again. [Here is similar Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688360/why-does-my-spreadsheet-function-behave-differently-than-when-called-from-code/15689022#15689022)

Comment: As suggested I changed .FindNext with 

Set c = .Find(What:=value, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    after:=c, _
                    MatchCase:=False)

but it goes into infinite loop.

Answer (score 4):

Got it... finally

Two things FindNext is not workign so as suggested by @kazjaw i tried .find and here is the working code. Dont forget to give additional condition and that is "firstAddress <> c.Address"

```
Public Function GetDuplicateCount(value As String) As Integer

    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 0

    With Worksheets(1).Range("A:A")
        Set c = .Find(value, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    after:=Cells(1, 1), _
                    MatchCase:=False)

        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                counter = counter + 1
                Set c = .Find(value, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    after:=c, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And firstAddress <> c.Address

        End If
    End With

    GetDuplicateCount = counter
End Function
```

Comment: If `c` is actually `Nothing`, then we will get an error if we try to get `c.Address`....

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the native Countif function?

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"IND")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but what I am interested in is searching a row and getting value form the same row but different column. I know the example which i gave you is the bad one. Sorry for that.

Comment: If you need to sum values from different column, you can use Sumif:

`=SUMIF(A:A,"IND",B:B)`

Comment: Its not about sum. I want to process all searched rows. Btw really appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but in O365 it doesn't work because there's no exit condition for the first address so it loops until it blows up. Note that `Is Nothing` and `.Address` must be tested separately or you'll get an error if the range is nothing.

Below with added exit condition:

```
Public Function GetDuplicateCount(value As String) As Integer

    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim c As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    counter = 0

    With Worksheets(1).Range("A:A")
        Set c = .Find(value, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)

        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                Debug.Print c.Address
                counter = counter + 1
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
                If c Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Loop While Not c.Address = firstAddress

        End If
    End With

    GetDuplicateCount = counter
End Function
```